# Regular Expression, bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to read an ASCII file `coordinates.ascii` that have one line only:

```
-I0.00130000258937/0.000899999864241
```

inside a bash script, and attribute `0.00130000258937` to the variable `x_inc` and `0.000899999864241` to `y_inc`.
guess that the regexp for `x_inc` is:

```
(\d.\d+)(?=/)
```

but I do not know the regexp for y_inc and also the sed or grep commands/syntax to implement the regexp inside the bash ..

```
x_inc=$(sed -n '(\d.\d+)(?=/)' coordinates.ascii )     # does not work!!!
```

Comment: probably the easiest way is to get the two numbers *separately* (two commands)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer.
In fact I just realize that:

Comment: coordinate=(`echo "$coordinates" | grep -o "[0-9.]\+"`)

Comment: will create an Array variable, that can be used to assign

Comment: x_inc=${coordinate[0]}
y_inc=${coordinate[1]}

Comment: 0.00130000258937 0.000899999864241

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just with bash:

```
$ IFS="I/" read _ x_inc y_inc < coordinates.ascii
$ echo $x_inc
0.00130000258937
$ echo $y_inc
0.000899999864241
```

Comment: Nice, just bash. purist ..! : )

Comment: dont forget to reset IFS with original content (IFSOld="$IFS" before and IFS="$IFSOld" after the instruction) to avoid some "strange" behavior on following instructions (if any)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu, not necessary. Notice there's no semicolon between the variable assignment and the read command. That means the variable assignment is only in place for the duration of the read command. Documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
x_inc=$(awk -F"[I/]" '{print $2}' coordinates.ascii)
echo $x_inc
0.00130000258937
```

```
y_inc=$(awk -F"[I/]" '{print $3}' coordinates.ascii)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version using `sed` and `read`. It reads both variables at once:

```
read -r x_inc y_inc <<<$(sed 's@[-I/]@ @g' < coordinates.ascii); 

# $x_inc is now: 0.00130000258937
# $y_inc is now: 0.000899999864241
```

Edit: or with process substitution as suggested in the comments

```
read -r x_inc y_inc < <(sed 's@[-I/]@ @g' < coordinates.ascii);
```

Comment: That would be a good place for a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution): `read ... < <(sed ...)`

Comment: Hey, thanks. At the beginning I did not know what I was doing .. Never worked with regexp before .. now it is clear

Comment: @glennjackman Added alternative with process substitution. Please explain why it is preferred over the first version?